# how to use a gradient to find another gradient?

Tags: functions, partial-derivative

Is it possible that given the gradient of a function at a point, that you are able to find the gradient of another function at another point given that the second function is a function of the first function.

ex/ let $∇f(2,-3)=(4,3)$. Let $g(s,t)=f(st,s^2-t^2)$. How would one determine $∇g(1,2)$. And What conditions does f have to satisfy?

Comment: Apply chain rule on function $g$ at point $(1,2)$

Comment: Assuming you know the multivariable chain rule, just calculate the partials of $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $g(s,t)=f(x,y)=f(st,s^2-t^2)$  so that $x=st$ and $y=s^2-t^2$ and  for $(s,t)=(1,2)$ we have $x,y)=(2-3)$.

The chain rule gives:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}t+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}2s
$$

that, for $(s,t)=(1,2)$ becomes:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\big|_{(1,2)}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\big|_{(2,-3)}\cdot2+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\big|_{(2,-3)}\cdot 2\cdot(1)
$$
and, from $∇f(2,-3)=(4,3)$, we have:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\big|_{(1,2)}=4\cdot 2+3\cdot 2\cdot(1)=12
$$

Do the same for the partial derivative with respect to $t$ and you can find the gradient that you are searching.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help... just wondering though, when plugging in the s for 2s, why does s become -3 and not 1?

Comment: It seems that I had a mistake and you are right!  Thank you.